# Graph a function $|\frac{\sin x}{x}|$

Tags: real-analysis, functions, graphing-functions

How can one graph a function $\left|\frac{\sin x}{x}\right|$,  $x\neq0$ without any program by hand? Without using derivatives.

Comment: The same way you graph any function.  Find where it is zero.  Plug in some points where you know the value of $\sin$.  Fill in the gaps.  "Without derivatives" you may need to just guess where it is increasing and where it is decreasing.

Answer (score 2):

**hint**

The function is even.

You begin by the graph $ C $ of $ \; x\mapsto \frac{\sin(x)}{x} $ at $(0,+\infty) $ and then its absolute value.

You know that

$$(\forall x>0)\;\; -\frac 1x\le \frac{\sin(x)}{x}\le \frac 1x$$

So, the graph $ C $ oscillates between the two hyperbolas whose equations are $ y=\pm \frac 1x$.

they intersect at $ x $  satisfying

$$\sin(x)=\pm 1$$
or
$$x=\frac{\pi}{2}+k\pi$$

Comment: It is important to estimate the value at $x=0$, which could be $0$, some finite value or $\infty$. This would make pretty different graphs.

Comment: The limit at zero is one.

Comment: Haha, thank you I know, but this should be in your answer !